# Entity Tables with Same Name having issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a situation where I have loaded two different databases into my solution using entity framework.  Both databases have a table called TBL_CONTACT.  Most of the fields are the same, but they have a couple that differ slightly.

I realize that when I generate entities, it creates one copy of TBL_CONTACT and creates fields for it based on the last entity I generated.

From what I have read, the issue is that the connection string is using a wild card after res://*.  What type of information should I place there to explicitly state the connection and not have it use a while card.  Is that even possible?

If I am looking at the wrong area, is there another way I can make sure the entities do not overlap and each have their own TBL_Contact?

```
<add name="ACTWhite2Entities2" connectionString="metadata=
     res://*/White2.csdl|
     res://*/White2.ssdl|
     res://*/White2.msl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework map the database tables into C# classes. However, if you have 2 tables with the same name, C# can't see 2 classes with the same name, so.. you won't see 2 TBL_Contact in C#, that's right.

To solve this and to differentiate tables in C# , you can give the entity classes different names. Just click on the entity class in the designer and change the name in the property window. Eg.: keep in a edmx "TBL_Contact" and onto another "TBL_Contact_New"